# How to transfer control from one window to another without the use of an event handler?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, attached-properties

Im new to programming and in need clarification for the following ...

I have a text box in which text is automatically generated .
Requirement: If i now highlight the text in the text box a new wpf window should open .. 
(this needs to be done using either wpf commands on attached property only/ not events)

Thanks :) 
P.s please give me detailed code for a reply ..

Answer (score 0):

This is a very strange requirement but it can be done using behaviors.  Here is some sample markup:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="This is some text">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:NewWindowOnSelectBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </TextBox>
</Grid>
```

and here is the behavior that for demonstration purposes shows a message box:

```
public class NewWindowOnSelectBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AssociatedObject.SelectedText))
                MessageBox.Show("New Window");
        };
    }
}
```

This example uses behaviors.  If you are not familiar with behaviors, install the Expression Blend 4 SDK and add this namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and add `System.Windows.Interactivity` to your project.